# Is it possible to mock a Java protocol buffer message?

Tags: java, mocking, protocol-buffers

Protocol buffer classes are marked `final`, presumably for efficiency; however, this makes them quite difficult to test with -- [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) can't mock/spy on final classes. I've tried using `PowerMockito` with no success: I get a `ClassFormatError` when preparing the `final` class for the test.

My solution up until now is to create mockable adapter interfaces, but I'm hoping there's a less laborious approach.

Comment: I can't see why you would need to mock a protobuf message class. If you need to use one in a test, just create it in the normal way. If you are mocking a service, you could just mock the ServiceClass.Interface.

Comment: @Geoff: That's a good point, using some simple values will work in many cases -- I was hoping to use the RETURNS_MOCKS functionality to avoid having to build the more complicated messages and verify certain parts of the message are read. I'll try other mock frameworks mentioned below to see how they go.

Comment: @geoffreedy but..... Creating the classes in the usual way turns my unit tests into integration tests.   :'(

Comment: @geoff-reedy: In the case of proto2 (where required vs. optional is a thing), there are instances where the core logic only functions on a specific subset of required fields of a given message (but still large enough of a cardinality of fields in the whole message that you'd want to pass the entire message into the method). In such white-box UTs, I really shouldn't have to need to care about constructing all the other "required" fields that my logic won't care about.

Answer (score 2):

[JMockit](http://jmockit.github.io/) can handle `final` and `static`. Just pay attention to how to set it up as it requires the -javaagent JVM parameter, or classpath tweaks, or extra annotations to be able to mock `final` and `static` stuffs.

Comment: JMockit fails to mock them with a java.lang.ExceptionInitializerError.

Comment: Did you try all the javaagent redefinition thingy? If you're trying to mock a system/core java class, you need to override the JVM boot classpath. Maybe your tests is missing an annotation? Sorry I can't be of more help. I'm not familiar with the class you're trying to mock or how you're approaching it.

Comment: Actually, it should be easy to get a JMockit test working: either add `-javaagent:<proper path>/jmockit.jar` as a JVM startup parameter, or add jmockit.jar before junit-xyz.jar to the classpath if using JDK 1.6. If it still fails, post your specific problem in the JMockit Users discussion group.

Answer (score 1):

JDave has an [Unfinalizer](http://www.jdave.org/documentation.html#mocking) that integrates with the [JMock ClassImposteriser](http://www.jmock.org/mocking-classes.html)

It can't unfinalize classes loaded from the the boot classloader, and it requires a VM argument when launching the tests.